# Is it possible to access camera in WKWebView on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

WKWebView is not asking permission for camera in the app. When I load the same url in safari browser it asks the permission for camera, and face recognition works perfectly. But when I embed this in WKWebView permission is not asked even I have given both camera and microphone permission in plist file. The same thing is not working even in UIWebView and safari view controller.

Comment: How about this answer? Looks like this is your solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43945157/14544835

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54674542/wkwebview-closes-when-opening-camera-swift

Answer (score 4):

This is a known limitation for WKWebView, WebRTC is only supported in Safari, not even in SFSafariViewController.

The only way would be to open the redirect URL in Safari.

Comment: Any other option to open it within app?