# WKWebView can't access camera on Iphone but no problem on Ipad

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm trying to open a React app that accesses the camera app using ***WKWebview***. The application asks for the necessary permissions when opening because the following part is available in my ***Plist*** file.

**"Privacy - Camera Usage Description"**

However, the problem I have is that the application works successfully on Ipad but not on Iphone. The iphone app just produces a black screen. What could be the reason why the same application works on Ipad and not on Iphone?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WKWebView closes when opening camera Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54674542/wkwebview-closes-when-opening-camera-swift)

Comment: No this is a different question and answer

Comment: How different? From how it's stated, it looks exactly the same. And the accepted solution is exactly what you should try first.